# copy all data from Kendo UI Grid Export to Excel

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a KendoUi Grid with excel, PDF inbuilt toolbar template, I am filling  the kendoGrid with ajax request for each page request I am doing ajax call to server and binding data to my grid.y because my grid have 100,000 records(to increase performence).so when I use all pages is true property it's not Exporting all records.

```
  var grid = $('#NewLeadsGrid').data("kendoGrid")

    var newdataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                $.ajax({

                    url: '/Reports/NewLeadsList',

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    dataType : "json",

                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        LifecycleStage: selfNewLeads.LifecycleStage(),
                        ShowTop: $('#NewLeadsGrid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.pageSize(), 
                         Filters: selfNewLeads.Filters(),
                         CustomStartDate: selfNewLeads.CustomStartDate(),

                         CustomEndDate: selfNewLeads.CustomEndDate(),
                        PageNumber: $('#NewLeadsGrid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(),
                        CustomPredicateScript: selfNewLeads.CustomPredicateScript()
                      }),
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (result) {

                       options.success(result);

                    }


                });
            },


        },
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total"
        },

        serverPaging: true,

        pageSize: 10

    });

    grid.setDataSource(newdataSource);

    grid.dataSource.fetch();
```

Comment: I haven't understand what exactly your requriement is, can you be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to export all data including paged data. This can be achieved using [allPages](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-excel.allPages) configuration in excel declaration. When you click the Export to Excel button, all data is read from the backend. Large data sets may have significant affect to page performance.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel"],
            excel: {
                allPages: true
        },
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10
        },
        pageable: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanq you japi ,But it's not the correct answer what I am expecting. my grid is not loading with all records at a time .for each page request I am doing an ajax call to server and binding the grid.when I am clicking the Excel in grid it's calling the read method and downloading grid current page data.

Comment: my grid have one l,00,000 records so I am using server side paging to bind grid for each page Request.

Comment: from 3 days back onwards  am struggling with this issue.

Comment: Then what is the issue?

Comment: it's Exporting current page data to Excel .but I need to Export all data.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. If you use allPages configuration, all data will be exported.

Comment: But I am not binding my grid at a time for each page request I am binding